# Ripping TV episodes from DVDs – how can I know which stream belongs to which episode?

Tags: linux, dvd, ripping

I'm ripping DVDs using a series of calls like

```
mplayer -dumpfile foo$i.vob -dumpstream dvd://$i
```

and using `lsdvd` to list the available streams to rip. Here is an example command I wrote for this

```
for i in $(lsdvd 2>&1 | egrep "^Title" | sed -e 's|Title: \(..\).*|\1|g'); 
  do mplayer -dumpfile foo$i.vob -dumpstream dvd://$i; 
done
```

For DVDs of TV shows, how do I know which streams go together for each 'episode', in other words, can I somehow rip the "episode guide" from the disc as well?

Comment: This really isn't the place for this sort of question.

Comment: @Ramhound Why not? I can rip anything I want from DVDs I own. The general consensus on DRM-related topics is that they're [given the benefit of doubt](http://meta.superuser.com/a/2215/48078) – and that's from Jeff Atwood, the site's owner.

Comment: I think he might have been trying to say that maybe another StackExchange site would be a better fit for this question.  Though I don't know what site that would be....

Answer (score 1):

For DVD ripping, I generally use a GUI program that can show previews, which makes it easier to determine which episode is what.  The tool I use most often is [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/).

How to determine stream/episode correlation from commandline, I don't know.

Comment: Handbrake is a good tool, thank you for the suggestion. For my setup, command line management is ideal and the server I'm using to store the vobs doesn't have a GUI (but has a lot of storage). Yes I could start up a window manager, but I prefer not to.

Comment: @payo In spite of the lack of GUI, you could x-tunnel Handbrake from the work machine to the "headed" machine you're working from.  As long as you don't have network lossyness, it should work OK.  I currently use several programs remotely (pidgin and transmission) from a machine that is dedicated to other purposes.